# Trace a function to stop its execution by using settrace and inspect frame

Tags: python

Using `work_block` function, how can I use the `inspect` and `sys` libraries to stop `print_text` function from printing hello?

```
import inspect
import sys

def print_text():
    print("Hello")

def main():
    work_block()
    print_text()

def work_block():
    # stop print "Hello" from executing 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. One that'll result in horribly ugly code.

Comment: I didn't pick this, I was asked to do it and I am really lost & unsure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need special libraries:

```
def work_block():
    # stop print "Hello" from executing
    global print_text
    print_text = lambda : None
```

But why would you want to do that?

By the way, the trailing colons when calling functions in `main()` produce syntax errors.